# TFS Build Number Format

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

TFS 2012 - Build - Build Number Format

Is there some way to remove or replace the DOT in the revision number?

Instead of

CRB_2016Oct06_.1

Just be

CRB_2016Oct06_1

I am using underscores for the rest of it, it's irritating that I have this period in the build name.

It seems as if no matter how you format it you get an error unless you include it.  Seems like such a silly thing to force users to accept a leading dot like this. It's just a darn integer.

Answer (score 3):

I could reproduce your scenario, `$(Rev:.r)` can't be modified in XAML build, if we modify it, we'll get error " Unable to expand the macro $(Rev:r) specified in build number format" when queue build.

But in the new build system of TFS 2015, we can simply change `$(Rev:.r)` to `$(Rev:r)` to remove the dot.

You may consider upgrade your TFS to new version and use the new build system instead of old XAML build. Or as an alternative, you can use `$(BuildID)` instead of `$(Rev:.r)` in XAML build, the build number format will look like: `$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)_$(BuildID)`.

Comment: Thank you.  I have already impressed upon management the importance of upgrading their version of TFS.  That will be at least another six months.  It's very easy to do this in 2015 from what I can see, yes.  2012 is a bit more of a challenge.  The only solution I can find is to create a custom activity to do this.  That's overkill on development work by a longshot, but it looks like it's my own route.